# 3D Nearest neighbour for query points located far away from set of points

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, computational-geometry, nearest-neighbor

I need to answer a lot of queries about finding nearest neighbour in pointset, locating far away from the query point. All approaches I've found so far work bad in this case (for example, k-d tree may have O(N) per query) or require use of Voronoi diagram (I have ~10m points so Voronoi diagram is too expensive).
Is there any known algorithm designed for such a task?

Comment: Wait, you mean that you trying to solve the k-NN problem and you set `k` too large? Or that the query is muuuuch far away from the pointset?

Comment: I mean I have a cloud of points, which are relatively close to each other. But my query point located far from this cloud (lets say, all cloud of points is in cube with center in (0;0;0) and edge size 1, and query points in (2;0;0), (4;1;3) and so on). K-d tree and other typical trees work bad in this case taking too much time to answer the query.

Comment: How about constructing the Voronoi diagram on only a subset of k well distributed points with k <<n? For query, you locate the Voronoi cell in log(k) and then do the kd-tree search on points of this region (there should be around O(n/k) of such points).

Comment: geoalgo, seems to be it's not enough to search only in kd-tree locating in best Voronoi cell. True nearest point could be in other Voronoi cell easily(and error could be quite large). But the idea is interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here are the distances. You see, when a query is far from your dataset, then the kd-tree has to check many points, thus slowing down the query time.

The scenario you are facing is hard for the Nearest Neighbor Structures in general (and it's not the usual case), but if I were you, I would give a shot with [Balanced Box-Decomposition trees](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/Papers/dist.pdf), where you can read more about their algorithm and data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Some multidimensional indexes have kNN queries that could be easily adapted to you needs, especially with k==1.
kNN algorithms usually have to first estimate the approximate nearest neighbour distance, then they use this distance to perform a range query.
In R-Trees or quadtrees, this estimation can be done efficiently by finding the node that is closest to your search point. Then they take one point from the closest node, calculate the distance to the search point, and then perform a range query based on this distance, usually with some multiplier because k>1.
This should be reasonable efficient even if the search point is far away.

If you are searching for one point only (k=1) then you could adapt this algorithm to use a range query that is exactly based on the closest point you found, no extra extension to get k>1 points.

If you are using Java, you could use my open-source implementations [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/zoodb-indexes). There is also a [PH-Tree](http://www.phtree.org) (a kind of quadtree, but much more space efficient and faster to load), which uses the same kNN approach.